# Need to be able to search by a field in a table from form input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function

I need to add a form input to search for a second column in a table.

I have tried adding a form. Tried manually putting what I am looking for in the SELECT line and it finds the data. Just need to be able to find it with form input.

```
<?php

/**
 * Mark as Paid
 */

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";

$success = null;

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $itemnumber = $_POST["submit"];

    $sql = "UPDATE consignsold SET paid='y' WHERE paid='n' AND sold='y' AND itemnumber = $itemnumber";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':itemnumber', $itemnumber);
    $statement->bindValue(':paid', $paid);
    $statement->bindValue(':sold', $sold);

    $statement->execute();

    $success = "Item successfully updated";
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}

try {
  $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM consignsold WHERE paid='n'";

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();

  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $error) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<h2>Mark Items as Paid</h2>

<?php if ($success) echo $success; ?>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<form method="post">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sale Number</th>
        <th>Item Number</th>
        <th>Lot Number</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Reserve</th>
        <th>Seller Number</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Buyer Number</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
        <th>Paid</th>
        <th>Mark</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["salenumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["lotnumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["category"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["itemdescription"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["reserve"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["sellernumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["amount"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["buyernumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["sold"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["paid"]); ?></td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>">Mark as Paid</button></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<br>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

If I try to add a form, I get a blank page. I expect a form with a place to input Buyer Number. As-is, the page works but displays all items and the operator has to manually find each item by buyer number and click the Mark as Paid button. What I need it to do is have an input where it asks for buyer number and only list those items with the mark button at the end. It is a closed-circuit operation so not worried about injections at this time.

The line: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM consignsold WHERE paid='n'";`
would be changed to something like: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM consignsold WHERE paid='n' AND buyernumber = <from form input>";`
Some have asked to clarify. . . I thought it was pretty clear to start with but. . .
REVISION: What I need on that page is a form input that asks the operator for a buyernumber and then uses the input from that form in the SELECT line to look for buyernumber and sold = 'y'. "buyernumber" is a column and "sold" is a column in the table: consignsold.
Thanks again to all who try to help!

Comment: The page lists items that have not been paid and as each item is paid, it leaves the list due to paid ='n' being changed to paid = 'y'.

Comment: @ dharman Yeah, I know. . . that is why I stated at the end that it is closed circuit and I am not worried about that at this time. I knew that would come up. . . Once I figure out how to make it work, then I will start trying to learn how to clean it up. I am new to all this. No training. Learning what I can from examples. . .

Comment: ok, I think I completely misread your question. You are trying to implement prepared statement, but all you get is a white page, right?

Comment: @dharman Didn't ask anything about a prepared statement. . . I need a form added to that script to ask the operator for buyernumber and have it return sold = 'y' and buyernumber = '<whatever from form input>' where it only shows items from a single buyernumber instead of the entire list. As-is, the thing shows the entire list of items that are sold = 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, I understand your question, but let me answer what I see is wrong.

First of all you should not catch the exceptions. This is considered a bad practice.

You also do not need 3 binds, you can just pass `$itemnumber` in the `execute()`. For this however you need to put a placeholder in the query. `?` is simpler than a named placeholder.

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

$itemnumber = $_POST["submit"];

$sql = "UPDATE consignsold SET paid='y' WHERE paid='n' AND sold='y' AND itemnumber=?";

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([$itemnumber]);

$success = "Item successfully updated";
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your input, but it answered nothing of my question. Thank you for pointing out some errors, though! I am still learning, here. . . So, try - catch are not necessary? YOW! it is in every one of my scripts, as in examples provided online. . . which I based them on.

Comment: Could you maybe edit the question and try to clarify it a little bit, please, because honestly I am lost. I don't know what you are asking of us, but I would like to help.

Comment: The page searches a table "consignsold" for sold ='y' and displays every item with that status. I need it to first ask the operator for input, in a form, that asks for the buyernumber, and then does a search in that table for that buyernumber and displays all items with sold = 'y' and the buyernumber that was entered in the form.

Comment: I see what you mean by not needing the binds. I will see if I can adjust some of my other scripts the same and see if they work. That will make it much simpler! Thank you on that one! I tried it in my live script and it worked just fine. If the binds are not necessary, what would be an instance in which you would be required to use one?

Comment: You need binds if you really need to specify the type of the value passed. By default everything is a string.

Comment: Got it. Did you see my rephrase of the basics of what I need?

Comment: Yeah, but it would be better if you edit it into your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: on a side note, taking out the binds actually broke the script. It didn't work anymore and I had to put them back. It would run but didn't do as expected.

Comment: I used ORDER BY and put in buyernumber. It still shows all items, but at least they are sorted. Would still like a form to ask for specific buyernumber, though.